# Post class only applying to first excerpt; why?

Tags: php, excerpt

I have a page with three excerpts.  Only the first excerpt is being given the post class, not the second or third.  I presume something is wrong in my PHP:

```
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
       <tr>
        <td width="100%" valign="top"> 
         <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
          <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
           <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
          <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
          <p><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?> at <?php the_time('g:i a'); ?> | <?php the_category(', '); ?> | 
          <?php comments_number('No comment', '1 comment', '% comments'); ?></p>
         </div>
         <?php endwhile; else: ?>
         <h2>Oops...</h2>
         <p>Sorry, no posts we're found.</p>
         <?php endif; ?>
         <p align="center"><?php posts_nav_link(); ?></p>
        </td>
       </tr>
      </table>
```

Here is the resulting HTML:

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center">

<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td width="100%" valign="top">
            <div id="post-19" class="post-19 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-printables">
                <h2>
                    <a href="myurl"></a>
                </h2>
                <p></p>
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <h2></h2>
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
            <h2></h2>
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
            <p align="center"></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

How do I ensure that the post class is applied to every single excerpt, not just the first one?

Comment: everything between `while` and `endwhile` gets repeated for each post, that's the loop. the thing you want repeated is outside that loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
          <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
   <tr>
    <td width="100%" valign="top"> 
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
     <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
     <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
      <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
      <p><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?> at <?php the_time('g:i a'); ?> | <?php the_category(', '); ?> | 
      <?php comments_number('No comment', '1 comment', '% comments'); ?></p>
     </div>
     <?php endwhile; else: ?>
     <h2>Oops...</h2>
     <p>Sorry, no posts we're found.</p>
     <?php endif; ?>
     <p align="center"><?php posts_nav_link(); ?></p>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
```